# How to send Arabic SMS using Clickatell REST API in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, clickatell

Here is my code

```
$to="[\"<mobile number>\"]";
$text = "غثس هفس خن";
$arr = unpack('H*hex', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE', $text));
$message = strtoupper($arr['hex']);
$authToken="3fUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "{\"text\":\"$message\",\"to\":$to}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array(
                        "X-Version: 1",
                        "Content-Type: application/json",
                        "Accept: application/json",
                        "Authorization: Bearer $authToken"
                ));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

When I am sending using this, I am getting some numbers as SMS

From Clickatell document, I got one solution that add a parameter named 'unicode' as '1'.

Then I changed the parameter line like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "{\"text\":\"$message\",\"to\":$to\",\"unicode\":1}");
```

Now I am getting `{"error":{"code":"100","description":"Data malformed","documentation":"http://www.clickatell.com/help/apidocs/error/100.htm"}}`

Comment: Are you sure that your php file is also encoded in `utf-8` ? If not, your `text` is not `utf-8` but the encoding used for your php file.

Comment: Yes, the file is in UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure that `UCS-2BE` is the destination charset ? Did you try to add a `charset` after the `content-type` ? I'm alson wondering if your whole `json` needs to be encoded with the same charset. Because, only `$message` is encoded in `UCS-2BE` and the rest of your `json` is `utf-8`.

Comment: Yes, I just convert only the message to UCS. Rest of the page is utf-8
Could you please give a sample code, that shows how it works?